# MATLAB how to get rid from whitespace when saving figures as JPG

Tags: matlab, border, jpeg, whitespace

I am writing a code for flowers recognition in MATLAB
but whenever I want to save a figure
it is saved with a white border - margin
how can I remove it
and save it as the exact size of the original image?
any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Whenever I run in trouble exporting figs I just use this submission from MC called [`export_fig`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig). Just download the file and place it in your working folder to use it. It was designed to export figure the way you see (whenever possible).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getframe(gca)` to grab the axes and not the entire figure (which is what would happen with simply `getframe` alone or `getframe(gcf)`). Then convert that frame to an image with `frame2im`. Then you can write that image to file with `imwrite`.

```
figure;
plot(x,y);
axis off
img = frame2im(getframe(gca));
imwrite(img,'myImage.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
figure('Color','none');
plot(1:10,1:10)
axis off
set(gca,'Color','none');
print ('-djpeg', 'no_background.jpg')
```

Comment: Won't this just change the background colour? You will still have the surrounding figure border outside of the plotting axes.